# SharePoint O365 with InfoPath for forms

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, infopath

My organization is currently using SharePoint Online.

We are looking to accomplish the following through leveraging InfoPath and SharePoint: Have manager fill out a forum --> forum goes to a third party to fill out ---> Third party fills out the forum and submits --> Everything is logged in SharePoint Lists.

Would this be possible to accomplish in InfoPath 2013?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look into integrating MS Flow.

A set up like this might help:

A single form list (contains the entire form that both parties need to fill out, designed in InfoPath)
When the manager fills in part 1, field 'Completed by manager' is (for example) update to say true, a flow then looks at that field and if it says true then sends email, with link to form, to next party to fill in their part.

While this may not be final solution, and requires consideration of the minor details, it is a good starting point.